# CSS Pseudo-Elements - using :after to position text under an image

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I have an image and need to add the text "click to enlarge" underneath the image but can only do this using CSS.

This is what I have so far, however, I cannot seem to position it properly.  It seems to float to the right of the image.  How can I get this to go directly under the image and to the left?

```
#main_image:after {
  content: "click image to enlarge";
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Put a container element around the image and justify the text relative to that container.

Comment: What browser shows that text? I created a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/hs4Pm/) but it doesn't show the "click image..." message.

Comment: These pseudo elements are supposed to be rendered as if they were an actual element inserted as the first or last _child element_ of the element you are using `::before`/`::after` on – and the `img` element can’t have any child elements, so this is why this is not _supposed_ to work (some browsers had a different idea about that in the past IIRC). If you are using HTML5, use [`figure`/`figcaption`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element) for this – and if not, just find some other container element to wrap the image in.

Comment: If you post a fiddle, i'm sure one of us will fix the problem easily enough.

Comment: @CBroe `:after` element is added as a sibling of assigned element's children ? If so, then why `+` sibling selector here does not work and enlarge the image? http://jsfiddle.net/ZJVyE/1/

Comment: @Heart: Because pseudo-elements don't work with sibling selectors. (Even if they did, `:after` would be the last child so it couldn't possibly have a next sibling.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of adding the caption using pseudo elements.

Your **HTML** might look like:

```
<a class="main_image" ><img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" /></a>
```

and your **CSS** could be:

```
.main_image {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 10px 10px 40px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.main_image img {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.main_image:after { 
    content: "click image to enlarge";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: beige;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Add the pseudo element to the `<a>` tag and then position it as needed.

I used absolute positioning but there are other options.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/fQyhj/

Answer (score 1):

Just add `display: block`: http://jsfiddle.net/fQyhj/4/

```css
#main_image:after{ 
    content:"click image to enlarge";
    text-align:left;
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    display: block;
}
```

I'm assuming that your `#main-image` is not the image itself, but some wrapper around it since you're seeing the text.

As a reference, pseudo elements do not work on "replaced" elements: http://www.red-team-design.com/css-generated-content-replaced-elements

Comment: @LeeTee How didn't it work? I just updated my answer with an edited fiddle from your accepted answer where it uses `block` and it looks exactly the same, with 3 less lines of CSS.

Comment: Sorry I didnt see the jsfiddle yesterday, I simply just added display: block; to my existing code and it did not work, i must have been missing something

Answer (score 0):

You have to add another `<div>` to do that. See the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hs4Pm/3/)**

I have used `margin-top: -80px;` to put the text on image.